# How to convert Ifc file to ifcXMLfile

Tags: xml, bash, terminal, autodesk, ifc

I'm working on a ifc file (3D building) and I would like to have it in ifcXML (or any XML format). I tried with IfcOpenShell (IfcConvert) but launching the computer terminal it says `Command not found`.

I tried this way on the computer terminal:

```
$ pwd
$ /Users/username/downloads/directory_ifcconvert
$ username:directory_ifcconvert username$ IfcConvert
$ bash: IfcConvert: command not found
```

Do you have any other way to convert into XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the permissions of IfcConvert as below;

```
chmod 755 IfcConvert
```

and run as below;

```
./IfcConvert
```